# Bad tags - how to delete

Tags: support

I was on the wrong site and created 3 bad tags.
How do delete tags?
.NET  WPF   C#

Question is too short.  That is about it - how to delete tags you created by accident?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags without any associated questions are deleted by the system once a day, so the simplest solution is to remove the tag(s) and wait for the system to do its thing.

I have fat-fingered a couple of unwanted new tags myself, so I can testify to the effectiveness of this method.

I see you have done this already, so [.net](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net) and [wpf](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wpf) should be gone soon. The [c#](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag will stay around because you didn't create it (it is applied to 168 questions here as of now, for some reason).

---

In the Stack Exchange FAQ:

[How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or “zombie”) tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754)

and the duplicate Andriy M mentioned: [I accidentally created a tag. How do I delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71123)